# How to use PHPExcel methods along with Laravel Maatwebsite?

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I want to add data validation such as dropdown list for a cell and so I have to use PHPExcel `addNamedRange()` function in a file using Laravel Maatwebsite. 
Creating a object for PHPExcel within the Maatwebsite's objects doesn't helped me.

Code:

```
Excel::create('Sheet', function($excel) use ($data) {
  $PHPExcelObject = new PHPExcel();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just validate `$data` before calling the static `create` method on the `Excel` facade?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to add data validation as dropdown list.

Comment: dropdown list means frontend validation, has nothing to do with Laravel

Comment: @CaddyDZ I think they want to add a dropdown list to the Excel cell, so interaction with the created sheet would limit that cell to a specific set of choices.  I do not believe that are referring to an initial validation of source data in the front end.  But I could be mistaken.

Comment: @matticustard Yes. You're right. I want a dropdown list in a cell of Laravel generated excel.